# Can't get the same CRS for different layers in QGIS

Tags: geocoding, shapefile, coordinate-systems, qgis

I have just begun to fiddle around with QGIS. Now, I have a .shp file containing a map of Sweden. I want to add a vector point to that map by adding a new point layer through the Delimited Text File plugin. The CSV file that I'm importing contains the following data:

```
id,lat,long
1,62.30000,14.10000
```

The dot appears on the screen but very far away from the country map. I assumed that was because the layers were set to different CRS, but after right-clicking each layer and changing the CRS to WGS 84, nothing changes. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Just go it to work by deleting the point layer, changing the coordinates in the CSV file to SWEREF99 TM, and importing the layer anew with the same plugin. But I'm still wondering if it's not possible to change the CRS after importing?

Comment: You might be interested in [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) for GIS-specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always change a layer's CRS by overriding the setting in layer properties - General tab. Note that the features are not reprojected when you change this setting. You are just telling QGIS to interpret the coordinates differently.

Comment: If you want to reproject the features: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73693/54637